# Show SVProgressHUD on viewWillDisappear

Tags: ios, swift, loading, svprogresshud, viewwilldisappear

Context : My `UIViewController` is showing an edit profile view, with a few `UITextField` (first name, last name, birthday, ...). There is no "save button", the values update on the database as soon as the `textFieldDidEndEditing` is called.

I want to show a loading view (I'm using SVProgressHUD library) if the user try to leave the `UIViewController` before all database updates are finished.

So here is my code (if updateWaitingConfirm is empty that means all updates are done) :

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    
    if !updateWaitingConfirm.isEmpty {
        
        self.showSVProgressHUD(message: NSLocalizedString("updateWaiting", comment: ""))
        
        timeToWaitCount = 0
        let group = DispatchGroup()
        group.enter()
        
        checkWaitingConfirmEmpty(group)
        
        group.wait()
        self.dismissSVProgressHUD()
    }
    
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
}

func checkWaitingConfirmEmpty(_ group: DispatchGroup) {
    
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
        self.timeToWaitCount += 0.5
        if self.updateWaitingConfirm.isEmpty || self.timeToWaitCount > self.maxTimeToWaitForUpdates {
            group.leave()
        } else {
            self.checkWaitingConfirmEmpty(group)
        }
    }
}
```

When all updates are done (or when it's been more than maxTimeToWaitForUpdates (10 seconds)), the `group.leave()` is called and then I call my function to dismissHUD and call the `super.viewWillDisappear()`

The problem is that nothing appears on my view, I also tried to edit a textfield for example and it doesn't work either.
I also tried to call `view.layoutIfNeeded()` after the showSVProgressHUD but it's not working.

Good to know : I can't just call a method on my back button `touchUpInside` method because the user can also quit the `UIViewController` with `interactivePopGestureRecognizer`.

Thanks!

Comment: You can't. When `viewWillDisappear`is called, it is going to disappear. You can't add anything to its view hierarchy. You could display the progressHUD on the root window or display it on the view controller that you are going back to. But, really is don't think this adds anything to the user experience. It just gets in the way. Save your data silently.

Comment: Easiest way will be to show it on rootViewController.
let viewController = UIApplication.shared.windows.first!.rootViewController as! YourViewController
viewController.showProgressIndicator